# Fixing the place of a Tkinter window (not a widget)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is the code for the window:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('200x200+400+400')
```

This window can be dragged to move from its place. How to to fix it in its place?

Comment: You can bind `<Configure>` event on `root` and call `root.geometry("+400+400")` inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not making the position permanent

Comment: How about removing the title bar so it cannot be dragged?

Comment: Call `root.overrideredirect(1)`.

Comment: I used root.attributes('-type', 'dock'). Worked perfect. Posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the window can be a non-fullscrean size, but it can't be dragged around like another application? I think that is on the operating system side of the problem. What are you making? Maybe there is a workaround.

It is possible however to make it forced fullscreen. For that Check here: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-display-full-screen-mode-on-tkinter#:~:text=Tkinter%20displays%20the%20application%20window,fullscreen%2C%20toolwindow%2C%20and%20topmost](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-display-full-screen-mode-on-tkinter#:%7E:text=Tkinter%20displays%20the%20application%20window,fullscreen%2C%20toolwindow%2C%20and%20topmost).

Comment: I am making a standalone dock for wayland. I am dissatisfied with the present options. Can the window be fullscreen and not resizable? I'll then make a background also :)

Comment: Added a link for you ^

Comment: Thanks! Will look in.